# Trouble getting rename working with regex groups

Tags: rename, regex

Folder of files that need to be changed to YYYY-MM-DD.pdf but currently are MMDDYYYY.pdf

This is what I came up with but it's not working

```
rename -nv 's/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4}).*/$3-$1-$2.pdf/' *.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the dry-run shows nothing. If I remove it nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The rename installed wasn't the Perl version. Once I switched issues resolved

Comment: switched from which version of rename? that needs mentioned in your answer at least.